# Error Spotting : He says that he has done engineering besides an MBA

Tags: articles, exam-questions

> He says that he has done engineering besides an MBA.

I have an error spotting exercise booklet as per which the above sentence is error free but isn't it better to omit **an** from the sentence ? To my ears *He says that he has done engineering besides  MBA* sounds better.

Comment: Your ears are wrong. The sentence is a horror to begin with, and will only be made worse by the omission of the indefinite article.  We have no way of knowing whether your "error spotting" exercise was written by someone who can actually speak and read English, so it is difficult to say what answer might be expected. Please use the **[edit]** link to add the entire exercise to your question.

Comment: @P.E.Dant What you need to do with entire exercise ? There are numerous sentences in that exercise but how they are supposed to be relevant so as to post them all here ?

Comment: If there is any explanatory or introductory text that precedes what you have provided, please add it to your question. If that is only something like _"Error Spot, Spot Below Error"_, that need not be added. The sentence provided as "error free" is extremely clumsy English. In any case, a proper noun like _**MBA**_ cannot appear without a determiner (such as an article like _"an"_).Your ears have deceived you.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Thanks for giving the answer that I was looking for  but I am sorry  there isn't anything as such given that you are asking, its just a plain error spotting exercise of comprehensive English with numerous sentences and answer key given. I don't even have explanation for the answers.

Comment: What is the source book or other media? I don't think error spotting is so helpful if its conclusions aren't reliable. Beyond that, we have no way to evaluate why it doesn't sound right to your ears.

Comment: In English, the names of academic degrees, even when abbreviated, are countable nouns that take an article in the singular: "Mary has earned a Bachelor of Arts, an MBA, and a PhD."

Answer (score 2):

I read it as though the author wants to say that this person has done some engineering study in addition to completing an MBA.

As a native speaker, I believe the error that the author intends you to find is that the term *aside from* should have been used instead of *besides*.  Though I would add the word *some* in front of engineering, it feels unnatural otherwise.